# NextJS: Can't we run getStaticPaths in home page?

Tags: reactjs, next.js

I am getting the following error while running the following code in pages/index.js

Can't we generate static paths from home page?

> **Server Error** 
> Error: getStaticPaths is only allowed for dynamic SSG pages and was found on '/'.
> Read more: https://nextjs.org/docs/messages/non-dynamic-getstaticpaths-usage

[image: Error Preview]

```
import Header from "../views/layout/Header/Header";
import Footer from "../views/layout/Footer/Footer";
import {API} from "../config/API";

export default function Home({ data })
{
    return (
        <>
            <Header />

            <Products data={ data } />

            <Footer />
        </>
    )
}

const { getResolverData } = API

export const getStaticProps = async () =>
{
    const req = await fetch( getResolverData.endpoint )
    const data = await req.json()
    return { props: { data } }
}

export const getStaticPaths = async () =>
{
    return { paths: [], fallback: 'blocking' }
}
```

Comment: In order for the page to be dynamic it needs to be declared with brackets `[index]`
https://nextjs.org/docs/routing/dynamic-routes

Comment: @IvanV. is correct - and in your case you probably don't even need `getStaticPaths` as your `/` route doesn't look like is meant to be dynamic. Jut remove `getStaticPaths`.

Comment: Also I guess `fallback` is not needed as Next.js twill just prerender it always at build as it is just a single page so won't be too slow.